# Using data URI for images in IE 6 and 7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, base64, internet-explorer-6, local-storage

I am currently developing a web-app. It contains images which are generated dynamically in the server (and thus takes some time to appear after requested) and then dished out. So I thought that I will use `HTML5 local-storage` API to cache the images, so that on subsequent requests for the same image, it can be served instantly. For tha, I plan to use base64 encoding of the image as the source instead of using a source URL.

Instead of requesting the image from the server, the `JS` will now first check whether that image data is currently available in the local storage (say an image with attribute `123` is stored in the local storage with **123** as key, and the base 64 encoding as the value). If yes, then just change the image's source with the value obtained from there. Else request the server to send the encoding, upon receiving which, it is stored in the cache.

Problem is `IE6` and `IE7` don't support it. There is a workaround, as described [here](http://www.phpied.com/mhtml-when-you-need-data-uris-in-ie7-and-under/), but that involves a server side CSS file to contain the image data. Since images will be generated on the fly, that won't serve our purpose. How else can I achieve this in `IE6` and `IE7`?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively don't try and cache anything clientside. Cache the generated images on the server side and host those images like normal. You don't need localstorage and cache it client side.

In other words:

1. generate image server side using your script
2. cache it somewhere like `/httpdocs/cache/images/whatever-hash.jpg`
3. serve the image in your document `<img src="/cache/images/whatever-hash.jpg">`

If generating an image takes 5 seconds and you have 120 concurrent users requesting 100 unique pages and your server script can only handle processing 4 threads at any given time that comes out to
5 seconds x (120 /4) / 60 =  **2.5 minutes** of server processing time before the last user in the queue's image is served and the data stored in localstorage.

The same time spent will be true if all users requested the same exact page. There would be no  real benefits from caching per user since every user will have to ask the server to generate their own image. Also since localstorage will get invalidated often the more the user does they will feel a considerately slow user experience and in my opinion bail on your app.

Caching the file on the server will have many more benefits IMHO. Sure it takes up server storage space but these days it's rather cheap and you can get a cloud CDN (example www.maxcdn.com) to combat the load.

If you still decide you need to cache client side, because IE6/IE7 doesn't support localstorage or data URI so check out the following

- You'll need a Web Storage shim for IE6/IE7 there's a list at https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills
- You'll need a way to store the generated image as blob temporarily and stick it in the storage. Example: http://robnyman.github.com/html5demos/localstorage/
- You could also use a Canvas Shim and a toBlob shim: https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js/

Comment: I had thought that too, but it isn't feasible. There will be thousands of users. If for each user we ave store a great many number of images on the server, it will become clumsy...

Comment: What exactly is the image(s)? And how many are we talking about per user?

Comment: The images are, say, as in Google Book Preview, you request a page, say 48, and it is served (if legal, of course!). These images are generated dynamically in the server, since only the book is stored as a `mobi` or `epub` file, and based on the client, (if it is an IPad or iPhone, or Kindle) it is served (that is why we can't just save each page as a separate image). And the number of users will be pretty big...:) No of images per user will be say 50 (based on an average estimate of the image sizes, and the 5MB limit of local storage)..

Comment: I'm inclined to still solve this by storing cached images of the pages on the server. I've edited my answer with my reasons why.

Comment: Okay, will check whether this can be done. That is, whether a CDN such as the one you mentioned can be used. That being said, is it not possible at all to do it client side?

Comment: Sure it is possible but you'll have to forgo using DATA URI method and use blobs and javascript for loading the images. I've updated my answer

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `blob` bit? Never heard of it! The local storage won't be a problem. since it is well supported in all browsers except IE6 and IE7, for which I will be using `jStorage`..

Comment: Negative. `FileReader` is not supported in IE until version 10!

Answer (score 1):

set the headers to inform the browser that the resource is cached :

```
header("Last-Modified: " . date("D, d M Y H:i:s", getlastmod()));
```

in PHP
or

```
Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
```

in .net

This way the browser will cache the resource.

Comment: what is your server-side technology, how do you get the images dynamically?

Comment: GWT..Setting headers like that with page-load is a no-no in this app, for a variety of reasons...

Comment: You can set them just for the images. You can set up a filter for your webserver that will add the Last-Modified to http header. You could also specify the expiration time as well.

Comment: you could use server-side or client side caching, for Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html . Look what would be best for you, also, read this guide: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html